# In fortran 90, how do I program the equivalent of a handle in matlab

Tags: matlab, fortran, handle

I have a Fortran90 function f(a,b). I need to use a 1D root finder that requires a function g(a), with only one variable a, to find the roots of f for various values of b.

In Matlab, I can build a new function g with only one variable a, with parameter b,

```
g = @(a) f(a, b);
```

with b being a parameter that can change in the main program and has scope in f also.

How can I do this in Fortran 90 or 95 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this as follows, although it is not fully equivalent to matlab's function handle (functions are not really first-class citizens in Fortran).

```
module roots
  implicit none

contains

  subroutine root_finder(f,b)
    procedure(func) :: f
    real, intent(in) :: b

    abstract interface
      real function func(a,b)
        real, intent(in) :: a,b
      end function
    end interface

    print*, g(2.)

  contains

    real function g(a)
      real, intent(in) :: a
      g = f(a,b)
    end function    
  end subroutine
end module
```

As you can see, the function of two variables is passed to the subroutine, along with the parameter `b`. The subroutine uses an internal function `g(a)` to evaluate `f(a,b)`. This function is, as it were, the "handle".

An example program, which defines an actual function `f(a,b) = a**2 + b`:

```
program example
  use roots
  implicit none    
  call root_finder(f, 10.)
contains
  real function f(a,b)
    real,intent(in) :: a,b
    f = a**2 + b
  end function
end program
```

Output: `14.0000000`

Answer (score 0):

Simple: use a wrapping function... If this is your original function `f`:

```
integer function f(a,b) 
  implicit none
  integer,intent(in) :: a, b

  f = a + b
end function
```

You could wrap it into a one-argument-function `wrapper_fct` with constant `b1` like this:

```
integer function wrapper_fct(a)
  implicit none
  integer,intent(in) :: a
  integer,parameter  :: b1 = 10

  wrapper_fct = f(a, b10)
end function
```

or, even simpler:

```
integer function wrapper_fct(a)
  implicit none
  integer,intent(in) :: a

  wrapper_fct = f(a, 10)
end function
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant b is a parameter so I cannot make it into a constant inside the wrapper. I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty example for a wrapper would be the following:

```
program omhulsel
implicit none

print *, 'f(1.,2.,3.) = ', f(1.,2.,3.)
print *, 'g(1.) = ', g(1.)
print *, 'g(1.,2.,3.) = ', g(1.,2.,3.)
print *, 'g(1.) = ', g(1.)
print *, 'g(1.,b=0.) = ', g(1.,b=0.)

contains

real function f(x,y,z)
  real :: x, y, z
  f = x**2 + y**2 + z**2
end function

real function g(x,a,b)
  real :: x
  real, optional :: a, b
  real :: par_a = 0, par_b = 0
  if (present(a)) par_a = a
  if (present(b)) par_b = b
  g = f(x,par_a,par_b)
end function

end program
```

The function `g` retains its parameters `par_a` and `par_b` (they get the `SAVE` attribute) which can also be modified by passing along optional arguments.

Comment: Don't use `save`, or even worse *implicit* `save`s... Down that road madness lies ;-)

Comment: Well, I did say "quick and dirty" :) Anyway, I wanted to see if the behaviour of the Matlab construction could be mimicked (which I think is the question), not that I think it *should* be done this way.

Comment: Hey, do I detect some Dutch language here (`omhulsel`)? Hallo ;)

Comment: @sigma: Hallo! Yes, sometimes that language slips into an example. Not from Netherlands though, flemish person living in Sweden ;)