# Integrating using Quadpack in multiple dimensions

Tags: fortran, numeric, numerical-integration

I would like to integrate a three dimensional function in Fortran using Quadpack:

```
function f(x,y,z)
...
```

I was thinking of something like this:

```
result = Integrate(B(x), a_x, b_x)
B(x0) = Integrate(C(x0,y), a_y, b_y)
C(x0, y0) = Integrate(f(x0,y0, z), a_z, b_z)
```

Quadpack expects a function of only one argument. How can I implement this in Fortran? Modules might do the trick, but is there something easier?

Comment: What did *you* try so far?

Comment: I googled and realized that Fortran doesn't provide anonymous functions. I don't want a full code. I would like to know "the standard approach"

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391991/in-fortran-90-how-do-i-program-the-equivalent-of-a-handle-in-matlab and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26297170/fortran-minimization-of-a-function-with-additional-arguments

Comment: You could use cubature integration like feynarts.de/cuba/ but you will have to calculate the Jacobian since it does integration over a unit hypercube.