# Numerical integration with undeclarable argumnets

Tags: fortran, integration, numerical

I'm trying to solve a 2 dimensional `(f(x,y))` numerical integral in FORTRAN. I learned that there is a standard form for function and boundary levels determination. My function has other variables like below:

```
Function=f(a1,a2,a3,c0,X,Y)
real(kind=8) :: a1,a2,a3,X,Y,c0(6,6),f(3,3,3,3)
```

I wonder how can I declare the `a1,a2,a3,c0` and `f` (the function output) globally to use the standard form for numerical integration `(f(x,y))`?

Comment: Well in a module, which is the more modern common block. Take a crack at it and post an attempt, for us to start with.

Comment: This is a common problem and is being asked repeatedly. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38324934/function-with-more-arguments-and-integration http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26297170/fortran-minimization-of-a-function-with-additional-arguments  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37714406/implementing-anonymous-functions-in-fortran?noredirect=1&lq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391991/in-fortran-90-how-do-i-program-the-equivalent-of-a-handle-in-matlab?noredirect=1&lq=1